# Wrong information in metadata/properties for IFC file

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-model-derivative

When calling 
https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/designdata/{urn}/metadata/{guid}/properties
over IFC file, the response contains wrong information. Instead of returning the property name, it returns it's type. Example

```html
"properties": {
          "Item": {
            "LcOaNode:LcOaNodeGuid": "c13f6c25-d776-584a-8b84-c7132760a018",
            "LcOaNode:LcOaNodeHidden": 0,
            "LcOaNode:LcOaNodeIcon": "File",
            "LcOaNode:LcOaNodeMaterial": "",
            "LcOaNode:LcOaNodeRequired": 0,
            "LcOaNode:LcOaSceneBaseClassUserName": "File",
            "LcOaNode:LcOaSceneBaseUserName": "3d337589-4cea-4301-a236-4b39c1e15ac9.Ifc",
            "LcOaNode:LcOaUnit": "Millimeters"
          },
          "Material": {
            "LcOaExMaterial:LcOaMaterialAmbient0": 1,
            "LcOaExMaterial:LcOaMaterialAmbient1": 1,
            "LcOaExMaterial:LcOaMaterialAmbient2": 1,
            "LcOaExMaterial:LcOaMaterialDiffuse0": 1,
            "LcOaExMaterial:LcOaMaterialDiffuse1": 1,
            "LcOaExMaterial:LcOaMaterialDiffuse2": 1,
            "LcOaExMaterial:LcOaMaterialEmissive0": 0,
            "LcOaExMaterial:LcOaMaterialEmissive1": 0,
            "LcOaExMaterial:LcOaMaterialEmissive2": 0,
            "LcOaExMaterial:LcOaMaterialShininess": 0.00001,
            "LcOaExMaterial:LcOaMaterialSpecular0": 0,
            "LcOaExMaterial:LcOaMaterialSpecular1": 0,
            "LcOaExMaterial:LcOaMaterialSpecular2": 0,
            "LcOaExMaterial:LcOaMaterialTransparency": 0
          }, ....
```

Where "LcOaExMaterial:LcOaMaterialAmbient0" is returned for example, it should be the property's name.

Comment: did the suggestion helped?

Answer (score 0):

IFC files are extracted via Navisworks and this is an expected behaviour. For a given property, you can use the displayName (if available).